# Generic class that accepts either of two types

Tags: java, generics

I want to make a generic class of this form:

```
class MyGenericClass<T extends Number> {}
```

Problem is, I want to be acceptable for T to be either Integer or Long, but not Double. So the only two acceptable declarations will be:

```
MyGenericClass<Integer> instance;
MyGenericClass<Long> instance;
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is no.  At least there is no way to do it using generic types.  I would recommend a combination of generics and factory methods to do what you want.

```
class MyGenericClass<T extends Number> {
  public static MyGenericClass<Long> newInstance(Long value) {
    return new MyGenericClass<Long>(value);
  }

  public static MyGenericClass<Integer> newInstance(Integer value) {
    return new MyGenericClass<Integer>(value);
  }

  // hide constructor so you have to use factory methods
  private MyGenericClass(T value) {
    // implement the constructor
  }
  // ... implement the class
  public void frob(T number) {
    // do something with T
  }
}
```

This ensures that only `MyGenericClass<Integer>` and `MyGenericClass<Long>` instances can be created.  Though you can still declare an variable of type `MyGenericClass<Double>` it will just have to be null.

Comment: Where is the benefit of using generic then? Since making a method having parameter of Type T will accept any number?

Comment: In your code, it is definitely not. Since cannot write method accepting param of Type T. You have to write two separate definitions of each such method, one for Integer and the other for Long.

Comment: @djaqeel That's not true.  If you try to use the frob method with something other than a Long or an integer you will get a compiler exception.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing in Java generics to allow this. You might want to consider having a non-generic interface, implemented by `FooIntegerImpl` and `FooLongImpl`. It's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I thought about that, and it would solve my problem. I was just wondering if java generics allowed me to do it without having to declare this classes. But I won't use interfaces, because the implementations of both classes is the same. I'll create an abstract package protected class and make two public classes that extend it.

Comment: And as for what I'm trying to achieve, I want to create a class that makes sense for Integer, Long or any other int-like type, but it doesn't make sense to use it with floating point types.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a class that accepts either of two types. That has already been answered above. However I will also answer how you can extend that idea to a method within the class you are using without need for creating another class for this. You want to use just : -

- Integer
- Long
- Not Double

  ```
  private <T extends Number> T doSomething(T value) throws IllegalArgumentException{

         if(value instanceof Integer){
              return (Integer)value;
          }
        else if(value instanceof Long){
              return new value.longValue();
          }
        else
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("I will not handle you lot");
  }
  ```