# Why Java generics do not support OR clauses for wildcards?

Tags: java, generics

I am coping with a situation where I would like to have a generic of the type

```
MyGeneric<T extends A | B>
```

i.e. something mirroring

```
MyGeneric<T extends A & B>
```

. This last is allowed, given B is an interface; the reason for not accepting B as a class is that Java does not support multiple inheritance *explicitly*.

From [Generic class that accepts either of two types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141960/generic-class-that-accepts-either-of-two-types) I get the confirmation that my guess on the OR clause for a generic is not acceptable for Java. This means that my guess on the OR clause is syntactically incorrect, regardless of B being a class or an interface.
So I am wondering why Java does not support this. Is there any stronger reason than "not implemented"?

---EDIT---

Of course there are plenty of situations where OR clause could cause doubts (see comments and answers), but look at my case:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractTask<T extends MyAbstractCommand> {
    @Override
    final protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
           T response = null;

           Gson gson = new Gson();
           response = gson.fromJson(result, clazz);7
           postProcess(response);
        }
    }
    abstract void postProcess(T task);
}
```

In this case I am applying a Template Method Pattern + Command Pattern. So T is the command and postProcess takes care of running it.

Now I can have something like

```
public class MyTask extends MyAbstractTask<MyCommand> {...}
```

and it is cool.

However, suppose you create a "YourCommand" class. If it does not relate to MyAbstractCommand, I am forced to duplicate the reported code or to create a common interface implemented by both abstract commands or to let YourCommand extend MyAbstractCommand. If supporting OR clause, I could just add YourCommand to the list of accepted parameter types for my generic.

Comment: A problem with `|` would be that `A` and `B` may don't have any similarities. Therefore `myGeneric.methodInAOnly()` will be a problem if `myGeneric` is of type `B`. Generics are there to make sure, that this couldn't happen.

Comment: Introduce an interface which holds the common methods and use this...

Comment: @Tom `A` and `B` always have similarities: They inherit `Object`. But I suppose it's not implemented/specified is, that this causes lots of uncertainity: There is no fixed type (or just implecitely).

Comment: @MrTux The point is not finding another solution, which I had already proposed. Btw, that specific solution your proposed is not always possible, as you are not always allowed to edit both classes. Having the OR clause would be the solution, with no side-effects, I guess.

Comment: @Manu that specific solution is always possible even if you have no control of the source:  Imagine `interface A{void f();} interface B{void f();}` where A and B are out of your control.  You create `interface T{void f();} T transform(final A a){return new T(){void f(){a.f();}} T transform(final B b){return new T(){void f(){b.f();}}`  Now you write your code using your interface T and your wrapper methods.

Comment: This would work only for known methods, as it is an adapter pattern. So i should create a Method in the adapter for each Method I want to use in any Class. This is a lot of code and work.

Answer (score 5):

If java generics did support OR clauses then what about the questions in the comments:

```
<T extends Runnable | Callable<?>> void fun(T wtf)throws Exception{
      wtf.run(); // is this a compile time error?
      wtf.call(); // is this a compile time error?
}

void main(Runnable runnable, Callable<?> callable){
      fun(runnable); // is this a runtime error?
      fun(callable); // is this a runtime error?
}
```

Comment: I understand why this should not be allowed, but your point just limits the potential scope of the OR clause. So, you should not be able to call run or call on wtf, as they do not belong to both Runnable and Callable. However, there are still cases when the OR clause is useful, e.g. the situation reported in the linked thread.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit to support my thesis that OR clause would be reasonable in some cases.

Comment: @Manu If you cannot rely that generics will work for 100%, then the system is unreliable and worthless. Then you can use the "old" system by using `instanceof` and `casting`.

Comment: @Tom I am not saying that it should be allowed not to work. What emory showed is a case where syntactic errors should exist.

Comment: @Manu I think what you are describing is similar to "duck typing".  In certain limited situations it would work.  I think the creators of java explicitly chose to disallow it (even in those situations it might work) because of issues like the wine/trousers problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#Criticism

Comment: In general, duck typing may lead to abuse of such a potential OR clause in generics. However, there are some cases where the usefulness of the OR clause would exist in absence of duck typing. The one I reported is an example (think of B as a "Boolean" or a third party library class).

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer as it implies that the OP's question is an impossibility. It certainly is not. Your question can be answered with how Ceylon solves this problem: by requiring pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Ceylon achieves this with [union types](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.0/tour/types/). Since this language exists on the JVM stack this means there are no technical limitations that would disallow such a feature (nor can I think of such a limitation). Nevertheless, one might argue that such a feature is less desirable, especially when the language supports mixins/traits/default methods.

Personally I prefer the usage of the [interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and the usage of intersection types. That is much cleaner in terms of readability and maintainability. Of course this is not always possible, especially when working with third party libraries. Therefore it is not a bad idea (I guess the guys at Redhat also thought so).

So to combine both arguments into an answer to your question:

> Is there any stronger reason than "not implemented"?

There is no technical limitation, but it is not a great idea, therefore it has not been a priority, and it probably will not be for a long time.

Comment: Thanks. Also in case of full application of the interface segragation principle, there might be situations (as you mentioned, third party libraries) where you have to look for a tradeoff. The OR clause in generics would be the perfect tradeoff.