# How to parse different types of parameter in one method

Tags: java

In Java I want to combine 3 overloaded methods into one general method as followed:
method 1:

```
public void method1(String name, String Para){......}
```

// Student is a object
method 2:

```
public void method2(String name, Student para){....}
```

method 3:

```
public boolean method3(String name, List <Student> para){...}
```

How could I combined above 3 methods to one, it should be as followed after combining:

```
public boolean generalMethod(String name, ?????? para){....}
```

Should I use generic parameter in Java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would make no sense to make one "general" method then cast everything from `Object`.  The preferred solution would be to have the methods with the same name, but different signatures (parameter overloading). Or create a class with sublcasses, each subclass implements one type of argument, e.g. `StudentParameter`, with one method that calculates the boolean value and use the strategy pattern (which is a huge overhead here:) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/):

```
public class MyService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyService myService = new MyService();

        myService.method("name", "hello");
        myService.method("name", new Student());
        myService.<List<Student>>method("name", Lists.newArrayList(new Student()));
    }

    public <T> void method(String name, T para) {
        System.out.println(para);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely an ugly solution buy you can do following

```
public boolean generalMethod(String name, Object para){....}
```

and in the method you can check the type of `para` using `instanceof` operator

**Update**

As there is no direct relations among these parameters you cannot use generic directly.(actually you can use type Object in generic but dont add much value). If there was a common parent class then you could use that.

you can do similar thing suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9142125/931982)

Comment: Thanks, could I use generic parameter? e.g <T>, is generic parameter accept List type, object type and String type? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since all the classes extend `Object` class, so you can use

```
public boolean generalMethod(String name, Object para){....}
```