# Java accept different type of parameters without overloading

Tags: java, java-8

Here is a very simple example:

```
private boolean f(List x) {
    return x != null && !x.isEmpty();
}

private boolean f(Map x) {
    return x != null && !x.isEmpty();
}
```

Code inside both function is same, they just operate on different objects. I want to merge them into one function to avoid code repeatation.

I tried something like:

```
private <T> boolean f(T x) {
    return x != null && !x.isEmpty();
}
```

But it gives error on `x.isEmpty()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generics parameter bounding to any of a range of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592832/java-generics-parameter-bounding-to-any-of-a-range-of-types)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, just use apache-commons.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141960/generic-class-that-accepts-either-of-two-types

Comment: @SergeyMorozov apache-commons?

Comment: @pushkin not a duplicate, there is no common bound for a `List` and `Map` that you could call `isEmpty` on

Comment: and what is the use to close this with a duplicate that simply says "you can't"? There are good answers here anyone voting to close it for that duplicate should retract their votes IMO

Comment: Merging them is actually more complicated than leaving them separated.

Answer (score 13):

Where the parts of what you want to use are covered by an interface implemented by both classes, use that interface.

But in your case, `List` and `Map` don't share an interface that provides `isEmpty`, so your options are:

1. Overloading *(the following is your code unchanged)*

   ```
   private boolean f(List x) {
       return x != null && !x.isEmpty();
   }
   private boolean f(Map x) {
       return x != null && !x.isEmpty();
   }
   ```
2. Accepting `Object` and using `instanceof` branches

   ```
   private boolean f(Object x) {
       // (roughly)
       if (x == null) {
           return false;
       }
       if (x instanceof List) {
           return !((List)x).isEmpty();
       }
       if (x instanceof Map) {
           return !((Map)x).isEmpty();
       }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // Or whatever
   }
   ```
3. Accepting `Object` and using reflection to get the `isEmpty` method (if any) and call it

   ```
   private boolean f(Object x) {
       // (roughly)
       try {
           return x != null && !(boolean)x.getClass().getMethod("isEmpty").invoke(x);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // Or whatever
       }
   }
   ```

Of those, overloading seems the cleanest approach *to me*, not least because it gives you a *compile-time* error if you try to use `f` on a type it can't handle (whereas the others are runtime errors, blech), but it's (at least slightly) a matter of opinion.

Comment: Good answer. An appoint. if x == null you should return false. Right?

Comment: @JoeTaras - In fact, all of my `return`s were inverted, I misread what `f` returned. Fixed, thanks. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I like point number 3 (plus one), I would use `MethodHandles` for this, though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714450/1059372

Answer (score 2):

You want to refer to both the List and the Map polymorphically using a common ancestor interface which sadly doesn't exist. Since Java is strictly typed the compiler is looking for a method definition which matches this signature which can't be found.

You can't do it precisely in the way you have asked.

Take a look at how Apache commons solved this issues with this method using `instanceof` to cast to a relevant type `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils#sizeIsEmpty`

```
public static boolean sizeIsEmpty(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection) object).isEmpty();
    } else if (object instanceof Map) {
        return ((Map) object).isEmpty();
    } else if (object instanceof Object[]) {
        return ((Object[]) object).length == 0;
    } else if (object instanceof Iterator) {
        return ((Iterator) object).hasNext() == false;
    } else if (object instanceof Enumeration) {
        return ((Enumeration) object).hasMoreElements() == false;
    } else if (object == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported object type: null");
    } else {
        try {
            return Array.getLength(object) == 0;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported object type: " + object.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follow:

```
private Object boolean f(Object x) {
    if (x instanceof List) {
        List l = (List)x;
        return !l.isEmpty();
    } else if (x instanceof Map) {
        Map m = (Map)x;
        return !m.isEmpty();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am a fan of `instanceof`. Nevertheless, every time I refer to it in any answer; other users immediately mention [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589590/why-not-use-instanceof-operator-in-oop-design)

Comment: @Yahya: Yes, you're right about your link. But in this case I suppose is very simple way to proceed

Comment: Instanceof is the worst thing in java, but if you like to use it, keep in mind that null check is not needed, because "x instanceof List" would return false if x is null.

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin:Yes, in my case if object is null it return false

Comment: @JoeTaras - you shouldn't add " l != null " and " m != null " condiitons - they are useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really, since `isEmpty()` is not inherited from a common interface. One workaround is to accept a predicate that determines emptiness:

```
private static <T> boolean isNonEmpty(T value, Predicate<T> isEmpty) {
    return value != null && !isEmpty.test(value);
}
```

Sample use:

```
isNonEmpty(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), List::isEmpty)
isNonEmpty(new HashMap<>(), Map::isEmpty)
isNonEmpty("foo", String::isEmpty)
```

Arguably this helper method is not all that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) , you can make you of [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class.

```
private static boolean isEmpty(Optional<Collection> collection){
    return collection.map(Collection::isEmpty).orElse(false);
}
```

---

Some example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList arrayList = null;
    System.out.println(isEmpty(Optional.ofNullable(arrayList)));

    Map map = null;
    //Convert Map entries to entryset (Collection) via Optional::map
    System.out.println(isEmpty(Optional.ofNullable(map).map(Map::entrySet)));
}
```

Output:

```
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

I love point 3 in [T.J.Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713394/1059372), but I would use a slightly different approach (and a bit faster):

```
private static boolean f(Object x) {
    MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class);
    Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
    try {
        MethodHandle handle = l.findVirtual(x.getClass(), "isEmpty", methodType);
        return (boolean) handle.invoke(x);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```