# How to specify my data type in the generic parameters

Tags: java, generics

Hey the thing I want to do has to do with java generics, is it possible to specify the generic type of the class in my parameters? I can't describe it very well that is why i would try with an example I have the following class:

```
public class List<T>
```

Is it possible to specify my `T`, because I would like it to be only Integer or only Boolean?

Comment: You can restrict the concrete types of `T`, but as it's only one parameter, you would have to find a common parent for `Boolean` and `Integer`, of which there isn't any but the inadequate `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify this constraint directly in the generic class type as explained by ernest_k since these two possible types don't have any ancestor common than `Object`, which means finally no constraint.
But you could still make your class API forces this constraint.
Make the constructor private and provide factory methods instead of.

```
public class Foo<T> {

    private Foo(){}

    public static Foo<Integer> ofInteger(){
        return new Foo<>();
    }

    public static Foo<Boolean> ofBoolean(){
        return new Foo<>();
    }

}
```

And use it such as :

```
Foo<Boolean> booleanFoo = Foo.ofBoolean();
Foo<Integer> integerFoo = Foo.ofInteger();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141960/generic-class-that-accepts-either-of-two-types) other SO question, the answer is no.

If you want to use `Integer` or `Boolean`, you cannot use the approach defined in this previous answer either, because to my knowledge, there is no class which is common **only** to the `Integer` and `Boolean` data types.

In your case, it might be easier to simply create overrides which accept `Integer` or `Boolean` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify the values of T a bit more clearer.
You can use : `List<Integer>` or `List<Boolean>` if you want to restrict it to a single type.
And you can also use something like this: `List<T extends Number>` which will accept only integers, floats, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the exact class which have subclasses as Boolean and Integer you can't define List strictly like this.

You can define list as:

```
List<? super Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But in this case you can put there every class which extends Object which is certainly not this what you want, but can be helpful in similar problems.

**For ex:**

When you got classes like: Animal, Cat, Dog.

Then you can make list like:

```
List<? super Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And add to it every class that is subclass from Animal :)